# Excel: Rank a subset with duplicated values defined by another column

Tags: excel, countif, ranking

I'm trying to create a column with a rank of values based on a control column like this:

```
(A)     (B)     (C)
Value   Control Rank
100     1       8
200     1       6
200     1       7
300     0       5
310     0       4
320     1       3
350     1       2
400     1       1
```

In col `C` I've used a combination of `RANK` and `COUNTIF` in order to get a general rank of all entries that accommodates duplicates nicely:

[image]

Now how I can do a rank on col `D` that only considers the values if the Control col `B` has the value `1`?

My goal is to have this:

[image]

Note that I need it to deal with duplicates in the same way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution for this problem:

```
=IF(B2=1,COUNTIFS(B$2:B$9,1,A$2:A$9,">"&A2)+COUNTIFS(B2:B$9,1,A2:A$9,A2),"")
```

One might expand the `B$2:B$9` and `A$2:A$9` ranges to `A$1048576` and `B$1048576` respectively in order to have it rank the entire sheet.

Answer (score 4):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IFERROR(MATCH(A2,SORT(FILTER($A$2:$A$9,$B$2:$B$9>0),1,-1),0)+COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)-1,"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's almost there, but If `A3` and `A4` are both `200` and the control value is set to `1` in one of them the rank will still count. If both `C3` and `C4` are set to `1` or `0` it works fine, the problem is if they've different values. https://ibb.co/2YvMB9V